# Android Studio: Monitor Network Traffic of APK

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Problem: I would like to install a already compiled APK on an emulator (AVD) and use the profiler from Android Studio (Android Studio 3.4.1 as well Android Studio 3.6 Canary 2)

Although, it doesn't matter which version for the emulator I use, for none of those APIs (23 - 28) the network profiler worked. The profiler itself outputs statistics about the cpu, memory and network, but the connections and requests of the network are not shown and it states `advanced profiling is unavailable for the selected process` (API >= 26). For API < 26 I get the same, even if I check the "enable advanced profiling"-checkbox in the Configuration-Settings.

I found some [old solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453949/android-emulator-how-to-monitor-network-traffic) or [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168278/advanced-profiling-is-unavailable-for-the-selected-process), but nothing of them worked.

Is this behavior (not being able to sniff network traffic of third-party-apks) intended, or should it usually work.

Thanks in advance,
cheers!

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like while opening APK as Profile or Debug mode in Android Studio blocks the network profiling for security reasons. Try Wireshark or `tcpdump`.

Comment: "Try Wireshark or tcpdump." - How would one use either of those for this problem? (step-by-step instruction would be great)